# Facebook automatic login needing double page load on Rails 3

Tags: ruby, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, facebooker2

With Facebook logged in and app authenticated, a Rails 3 site with Facebooker2 needs 2 page reloads until it automatically logs in to Facebook.

How can I make passive login work on first page load?

ruby 1.9.3p125, rails 3.2.3, facebooker2 0.0.16

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a reload if you use the Javascript SDK. To skip the page reload, you'd need to use the server-side authentication flow.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/